# Kendo grid with multi select text

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I want to make one field as a multi select text box in my Kendo grid, so followed the below link, and copy pasted in 'editorColumnTemplateFunction' function. It's working when I type some text and entered, but If I click outside of the field or anywhere, then the entered data are not retained in the select field. Where I did go wrong? Or Can anyone help me to achieve the below link's functionality to Kendo Grid?

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/multiselect-as-tagbox

And my grid,

```
 $("#rulesGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource_RuleGrid,
        height: 200,
        scrollable: true,
        batch: true,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "CustomProperty", title: "Property", width: "80px", editor: propertyDropDownEditor, template: "#=CustomProperty.DisplayName#"
            },
            {
                field: "Operator", title: "Operator", width: "80px", editor: operatorDropDownEditor, template: "#=Operator.DisplayName#"
            },
            {
                field: "Values", title: "Value", width: "100px",
                editor: editorColumnTemplateFunction
            },
            {
                field: "",
                title: "",
                width: "30px",
                template: function (dataItem) {
                    return '<span class="grid-icon"><i class="icon icon-delete" onclick="deleteCustomRule($(this))"></i></span>';
                }
            }
        ],
        editable: { confirmation: false },
        toolbar: kendo.template($("#addRuleTemplate").html()),
        noRecords: {
            template: "No rules found"
        }

    });
```

And the editorColumnTemplateFunction function,

```
function editorColumnTemplateFunction(container, options) {
    Valuess = { ValueName: "AD", ValueName: "AD" };
    $('<select id="RulesValue" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple"  ></select>').appendTo(container).kendoMultiSelect({
        dataTextField: "ValueName",
        dataValueField: "ValueName",
        //autoBind: false,
        dataSource: {
            data: []
        },
        dataBound: onDataBound
    }).data("kendoMultiSelect");


    function onDataBound(e) {
        $('.k-multiselect .k-input').unbind('keyup');
        $('.k-multiselect .k-input').on('keyup', onClickEnter);
    }
    function onClickEnter(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            var widget = $('#RulesValue').getKendoMultiSelect();
            var dataSource = widget.dataSource;
            var input = $('.k-multiselect .k-input');
            var value = input.val().trim();
            if (!value || value.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            var newItem = {
                ValueName: value,
                ValueName: value
            };

            dataSource.add(newItem);
            var newValue = newItem.ValueName;
            widget.value(widget.value().concat([newValue]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a demo of your issue in dojo.telerik.com in order to help us help you

Comment: Hi, Please find the sample dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/UzUmeSoR/5 This is not a exact one but you can consider as sample.  In the dojo,If we type any text and enter in the organization column, thats showing as multi tag but its getting cleared when i click out side of the organization field. And I need this muti tag funtionality in AddRule button. When We click the add button then it should create new row and accept the multi select tag functionality to the 2nd field.